# strtok and replace a substring in C++

Tags: c++, string, strtok

If I have a string "12 23 34 56"

What's the easiest way to change it to "\x12 \x23 \x34 \x56"?

Comment: do you actually want the string to show "\x12 \x23 \x34 \x56" when you print it out? Or do you want it to be a string with char 0x12 then char 0x23, then char 0x34 then char 0x56?

Comment: More towards the latter, I am eventually going to WriteFile() each char 0xZZ one at a time.

Comment: in that case, i believe that my answer below (at the bottom) is the solution you need.

Answer (score 2):

```
string s = "12 23 34 45";
stringstream str(s), out;
int val;
while(str >> val)
    out << "\\x" << val << " "; // note: this puts an extra space at the very end also
                               //       you could hack that away if you want

// here's your new string
string modified = out.str();
```

Comment: it avoid the extra space, just prepend a "\x" before you start and change the line in the while to be: out << " \x" << val;

Comment: though from his comments, it looks like he wants a string with chars 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78 not a string containing "\x12 \x34 \x56 \x78".

Answer (score 2):

You question is ambiguous, it depends on what you actually want:

if you want the result be the same as: char s[] = { 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78, '\0'}:
then you could do this:

```
std::string s;
int val;
std::stringstream ss("12 34 56 78");
while(ss >> std::hex >> val) {
   s += static_cast<char>(val);
}
```

after this, you can test it with this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
    printf("%02x\n", s[i] & 0xff);
}
```

which will print:

```
12
34
56
78
```

otherwise if you want your string to literally be "\x12 \x23 \x34 \x56" then you could do what Jesse Beder suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like so:

```
foreach( character in source string)
{
  if 
    character is ' ', write ' \x' to destination string
  else 
    write character to destination string.
}
```

I suggest using std::string but this can be done easily by first checking the string to count how many whitespaces and then create your new destination string to be that number x3.